# How to use a retail Windows 7 Professional license key to upgrade an installed Windows 7 Home Premium machine

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I purchased a retail version of Windows 7 **Professional** and installed it on a computer.  That machine has died, and I replaced it with a **new** computer which came with Windows 7 **Home Premium** already installed.

I'd like to have Professional, not Home Premium, on the new machine, and I don't want to pay for an "Anytime Upgrade" because I already have a valid Windows 7 Professional license (for the dead computer).

Is there a way to legally upgrade using my Professional license key?  I've already installed programs, data, etc on the new machine, so I don't want to reformat and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run Anytime Upgrade, and when you're prompted for a license key, enter your retail key. It should work just as well.

Comment: Yes, it should be okay; Home Premium to Professional is supported via Anytime Upgrade: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also probably just run the upgrade from the DVD. Make sure you run it from inside the existing system, or else it will install a clean installation (making a Windows.old, but still).

Comment: This is actually incorrect. I have tried running an upgrade from Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 7 Professional from the installation disk before, and the installer told me to restart and use anytime upgrade.