# can I upgrade my Windows 7 HP to Ultimate by inserting the key only?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a retail Windows 7 Professional license key to upgrade an installed Windows 7 Home Premium machine](https://superuser.com/questions/257212/how-to-use-a-retail-windows-7-professional-license-key-to-upgrade-an-installed-wi)

I have windows 7 Home premium 'Geniun' , can i upgrade it to Professional or Ultimate by inserting the key of the new windows and install the updates required ??

Comment: I'm sure this a duplicate, but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can upgrade without reinstalling or using a disk. Just run anytime upgrade and enter your key.

Go to Control Panel (icon view) > Windows Anytime Upgrade.

No, simply changing the key will not upgrade the PC to Ultimate.

Comment: thanks... i though i could Just change the KEY then windows will install updates automatically...

Comment: Partial credit to @moab didn't even notice you edited, thanks!

Comment: Cheers mate!...